# @HostListener OnClick for outside click does not work in firefox

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firefox, onclick

@HostListener OnClick does not work in firefox.
I tried onClick, onclick and onGlobalClick. They all work in chrome but no one in firefox.
Here is my code:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) { }

@Output() offClick = new EventEmitter();

@HostListener('document:click', ['$event.path'])
public onGlobalClick(targetElementPath: Array<any>) {
  const elementRefInPath = targetElementPath.find(e => e === this.elRef.nativeElement);
  if (!elementRefInPath) {
    this.offClick.emit(1);
  }
}
```

Comment: Can't you just add the (click)="" directive somewhere?

Comment: I wont global click "everywhere" except some elements. I use this directive because hide element when click outside and don't hide it when press some specific elements

Comment: The name of the method will not change things. Is it fired? Have you logged?

Comment: this is directive for an outside

Comment: is it working for chrome, edge and other browser?

Comment: It doesn't work anywhere. Have you checked the logs?

Comment: It works on chrome I have not edge. it does not work in Firefox only

Comment: I tried in chrome, firefox and safari. And the error log is full. Could you setup a plunker ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is what I tested in all browsers and it works:

```
 @HostListener('document:click', ['$event', '$event.target'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent, targetElement: HTMLElement): void {
        if (!targetElement) {
            return;
        }
        const clickedInside = this.elementRef.nativeElement.contains(targetElement);
        if (!clickedInside) {
            this.clickOutside.emit(event);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`event.path` returns undefined only in Firefox, but it returns an array in Chrome and Edge browser (ng-version="10.1.6").

Solution - use **`event.composedPath()`** instead of `event.path`, its returns same array in Firefox, Chrome and Edge browser.

HTML -

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Demo Button</button>
```

.ts -

```
@HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
    console.log('event------', event.composedPath()); // working in Firefox, Chrome and Edge
}
```