# How to do window.external in Angular 2

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, controls

I need to make a call from window.external on angular 2 and expose a json as parameter.

Something like the example below.

C#

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
   public class ScriptInterface
   {
      void callMe(string json)
      {
       … // Do something interesting
      }
   } 



   webBrowser1.ObjectForScripting = new ScriptInterface();
```

Angular 2

```
window.external.callMe(json);
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve that is by event :

- your external function emits an event
- Angular application listens to this event and take appropriate action.
    (for example notify a service, and this service will itself transmit a notification to your components that need to be affected and have subscribed to it, or as another example use a HostListener directive)

For a concret example:

https://www.javascripttuts.com/global-events-and-event-delegation-in-angular-2/

or

[Detect Click outside element in angular 4 using directives](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46010867/479251)