# Angular using @HostListener to listen to specific click of button

Tags: angular, angular10

I am using Angular 10 and I am currently listening to a button click by id using jquery.
I know this is not the right way to do this with Angular so I want to change it.

This is the current code:

```
$('#tbtn1').click((e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); 
  this.myMethod();
});
```

Can I use: `@HostListener` to listen to a specific button which is on another component as I can do with the example above?

How can I do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45994882/hostlistener-onclick-for-outside-click-does-not-work-in-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code and it works (ng-version="10.1.6"):

app.component.html -

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">Demo Button</button>
```

app.component.ts (`extends` other components) -

```
export class AppComponent extends DemoComponent {
    @HostListener('document:click', ['$event'])
    onClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.myMethod();
    }
}
```

demo.component.ts -

```
myMethod() {
    console.log('myMethod working!!!');
}
```

Comment: Does this work if this.myMethod() is on a different component as where the button is?

Comment: Yes, it is working, just need to extends other components, above code modified, please check.

Comment: The only thing I can't see is that it doesn't know what element (button) has been clicked?

Comment: just add `console.log(event)` and get every detail of element and event.